# Mismatch Cluster ID when start kafka and zookeeper for the second time

Tags: docker, apache-kafka

I have this docker compose for running confluent zookeeper and `kafka` together:

```
---
version: '2'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:7.4.0
    hostname: zookeeper
    container_name: zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
    volumes:
      - zookeeper-data:/var/lib/zookeeper/data
      - zookeeper-logs:/var/lib/zookeeper/logs
      
  broker:
    image: confluentinc/cp-server:7.4.0
    hostname: broker
    container_name: broker
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
      - "9101:9101"
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper:2181'
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://broker:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://192.168.13.184:9092
      KAFKA_METRIC_REPORTERS: io.confluent.metrics.reporter.ConfluentMetricsReporter
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_GROUP_INITIAL_REBALANCE_DELAY_MS: 0
      KAFKA_CONFLUENT_LICENSE_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_CONFLUENT_BALANCER_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_MIN_ISR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_JMX_PORT: 9101
      KAFKA_JMX_HOSTNAME: localhost
      #KAFKA_CONFLUENT_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: http://192.168.13.184:8081
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: broker:29092
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_TOPIC_REPLICAS: 1
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_ENABLE: 'true'
      CONFLUENT_SUPPORT_CUSTOMER_ID: 'anonymous'
    volumes:
      - broker-data:/var/lib/kafka/data

volumes:
  zookeeper-data:
  zookeeper-logs:
  broker-data:
```

Everything's works fine at first, but after i turn down containers and make them running again, I got this error:

> ERROR Fatal error during KafkaServer startup. Prepare to shutdown
> (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
> kafka.common.InconsistentClusterIdException: The Cluster ID
> vmR9HtjMQ1GSCA2Q_ePbjA doesn't match stored clusterId
> Some(0H-v-ckbTz6vl3tMv9D-YQ) in meta.properties. The broker is trying
> to join the wrong cluster. Configured zookeeper.connect may be wrong.
> at kafka.server.KafkaServer.startup(KafkaServer.scala:368)
> at kafka.Kafka$.main(Kafka.scala:114)
> at kafka.Kafka.main(Kafka.scala) [2023-07-06 10:57:47,457] INFO shutting down (kafka.server.KafkaServer) [2023-07-06
> 10:57:47,515] INFO [ZooKeeperClient Kafka server] Closing.
> (kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient) [2023-07-06 10:57:47,627] INFO
> Session: 0x10005d424560001 closed (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
> [2023-07-06 10:57:47,627] INFO EventThread shut down for session:
> 0x10005d424560001 (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn) [2023-07-06
> 10:57:47,631] INFO [ZooKeeperClient Kafka server] Closed.
> (kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient) [2023-07-06 10:57:47,653] INFO App
> info kafka.server for 1 unregistered
> (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser) [2023-07-06
> 10:57:47,656] INFO shut down completed (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
> [2023-07-06 10:57:47,656] ERROR Exiting Kafka due to fatal exception
> during startup. (kafka.Kafka$)
> kafka.common.InconsistentClusterIdException: The Cluster ID
> vmR9HtjMQ1GSCA2Q_ePbjA doesn't match stored clusterId
> Some(0H-v-ckbTz6vl3tMv9D-YQ) in meta.properties. The broker is trying
> to join the wrong cluster. Configured zookeeper.connect may be wrong.
> at kafka.server.KafkaServer.startup(KafkaServer.scala:368)
> at kafka.Kafka$.main(Kafka.scala:114)
> at kafka.Kafka.main(Kafka.scala) [2023-07-06 10:57:47,658] INFO shutting down (kafka.server.KafkaServer)

I'm using docker compose and I want to persist any required data (`zookeeper` data and logs, broker data). I tried some solutions I found in the web and communities, but they don't work.

Comment: Are you sure you mounted the volumes in the correct location? The `meta.properties` file isn't stored in the data folder

Comment: @OneCricketeer yes, the `meta.properties` file is located in `/var/lib/kafka/data` inside the `kafka broker container`, but I don't understand why this happened!

Comment: @OneCricketeer where does `meta.properties` file locate? And what path should I mount?

Comment: The issue is that that file is auto-generated and creates a unique ID for the broker. When you restart, and it is not the same, then the cluster will fail to start. This is done to prevent new brokers from joining the incorrect cluster after one is already running. I personally have not ran into this error when using my containers (I use bitnami, not Confluent), so I don't have any suggestions for a fix. One solution you could try is to use Kraft mode, and remove Zookeeper

Comment: @OneCricketeer I created docker containers using `KRaft` mode, but I read somewhere that `KRaft` isn't ready for production, is that correct or not?

Comment: Depends what features you need (like certain security modes, or automated upgrades from Zookeeper mode), but no, it was announced production ready around 3.3 release